# can I put a toggleswitch in application bar in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, application-bar, toggleswitch

**like this picture below**
inside the application bar,we can see two toggle switch here
*If possible,How to implement this???*
ANY ADVICE WILL BE GREAT!
[image: Like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible! Only simple text labels with actions are available, nothing else...

I'd assume that specific app uses some sort of OEM API, which is not available in the public SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build your own custom application bar's user control that you can use in bottom of the page.